# How do I change multiple reference tags in XML based on spreadsheet values

Tags: excel, vba

I am a technical writer and not much of a coder, I have thousands of .xml files that combined create a book. I used a VBA script from this website to rename all of the files to fit within the new guidelines, now I need to go into the xml code and find all references to those links and replace them with the new file name.

I have an excel spreadsheet where in column A it has the old file name and in column B it has the new file name.

The tag looks like this:

```
<?iads.link docref="R381"?>
```

It needs to find `"R381"` in column A and replace it with `"R01081-1-1520-237"`, the file name in the adjacent cell in column B.

The Tag needs to look like this:

```
<?iads.link docref="R01081-1-1520-237"?>
```

I tried using the code from the question [How can I Find/Replace multiple strings in an xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15456892/6352151) but it did not work and I'm not even sure if that's the correct question to be asking

My current code looks lie this:

```
Option Explicit ' Use this !

Public Sub ReplaceXML(rFindReplaceRange As Range) ' Pass in the find-replace range

    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Edit as needed
    sFileName = "C:\Users\s37739\Desktop\chap3"

    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

    Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
        Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
        sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
    Loop

    Close iFileNum

    ' Loop over the replacements
    For i = 1 To rFindReplaceRange.Rows.Count
        If rFindReplaceRange.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            sTemp = Replace(sTemp, rFindReplaceRange.Cells(i, 1), rFindReplaceRange(i, 2))
        End If
    Next i

    ' Save file

    iFileNum = FreeFile

    ' Alter sFileName first to save to a different file e.g.
    sFileName = "C:\Users\s37739\Desktop\chap3"
    Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum

    Print #iFileNum, sTemp

    Close iFileNum

End Sub
Sub mike1()

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us more on why the referenced code did not work for you? What are the issues with the code that you could not solve? Are you getting errors?

Comment: when I hit F5 to execute the script nothing happens. On the rename script I ran it would ask me to direct it to a folder where the files were located. with the find replace script it did nothing... that is why I was not sure if I had the right script or not.

Comment: Have you changed the parameters from the script? The Find/Replace script contains values directly in the code, such as `sFileName = "C:\temp\filelocation.xml"`. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41702769/edit) your question and include your current code so it will be easier to assist :)

Comment: the only thing I changed was the file path to where the files to be located were edited, where it states "C:\Users\s37739\Desktop\chap3"

Comment: BTW thank you Victor for looking at this... any help you can offer is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the file path when in fact you should be passing the fully qualified file name (file path and file name). 
You need to edit those lines

```
' Edit as needed
sFileName = "C:\Users\s37739\Desktop\chap3"

'... 

' Alter sFileName first to save to a different file e.g.
sFileName = "C:\Users\s37739\Desktop\chap3"
```

With

```
' Edit as needed
sFileName = "C:\Users\s37739\Desktop\chap3\yourfilename.xml"

'... 

' Alter sFileName first to save to a different file e.g.
sFileName = "C:\Users\s37739\Desktop\chap3\yourNEWfilename.xml"
```

Also, remember to provide the correct Range when running the procedure.
Supposing your Range goes from "A1:B50" you can edit your `mike1` sub as follows:

```
Sub mike1()
    ' Change range as desired
    Call ReplaceXML(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range("A1:B50")) 
End Sub
```

After that, all you need to do is run `mike1` from the Immediate window.
Access using Alt+F11 for the VBA editor then View -> Immediate.
You should see a new window at the bottom of the screen. Just type `mike1` in there and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

**UPDATE:**
Ideally, you should first try to understand the code you currently have and change it make it work on multiple files instead of a single one per run. There are many places around that can give you examples on how to do that, either recursively or in a loop directly into a function. There are many ways to do it and also many material around it.

That being said, you can find below one of the many approaches to solve your issue. The following code consists of two `Sub`s that you can copy/paste into your module.

You need to change the value of `HOST_PATH` with the main folder and the `findReplaceRange` with the range to work with. You need to change `"Sheet1"` with the name of your worksheet and the `"A1:B10"` with your actual range. After that, just run the `ReplaceXML2()` Sub.

**Note:** this will update **ALL** XML files under the folder provided, so make sure you gave it enough testing (preferably, backup your files) before running it for the entire folder. If you have further issues I suggest asking another question.

**Code:**

```
Public Sub ReplaceXML2()

    Const HOST_PATH = "C:\Users\s37739\Desktop\chap3\"    ' change accordingly
    Dim findReplaceRange As Range
    Set findReplaceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10") ' change accordingly

    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Call RecursivelyReplaceXML(FileSystem.GetFolder(HOST_PATH), findReplaceRange)

End Sub

Public Sub RecursivelyReplaceXML(parentFolder, rFindReplaceRange As Range) ' Pass in the folder and the find-replace range

    Dim subFolder As Object
    For Each subFolder In parentFolder.SubFolders
        RecursivelyReplaceXML subFolder, rFindReplaceRange
    Next

    Dim file As Object
    For Each file In parentFolder.Files

        If Right(file.Name, 4) = ".xml" Then

            Dim iFileNum As Integer
            Dim sTemp As String
            Dim sBuf As String
            Dim i As Long
            Dim fullFileName As String

            fullFileName = file.Path
            iFileNum = FreeFile
            Open fullFileName For Input As iFileNum

            sTemp = ""  ' clean up to read the next file
            Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
                Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
                sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
            Loop

            Close iFileNum

            ' Loop over the replacements
            For i = 1 To rFindReplaceRange.Rows.count
                If rFindReplaceRange.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
                    sTemp = Replace(sTemp, rFindReplaceRange.Cells(i, 1), rFindReplaceRange(i, 2))
                End If
            Next i

            ' Save file
            iFileNum = FreeFile

            ' WARNING: New name definition commented out,
            ' which means all files will be replaced with newer versions!!
            '===
            ' Alter fullFileName first to save to a different file e.g.
            ' fullFileName = "C:\Users\s37739\Desktop\chap3\"
            Open fullFileName For Output As iFileNum

            Print #iFileNum, sTemp

            Close iFileNum

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: There are thousands of files to run this on. 

Is it possible to tell it to open the first file then search the excel list for REF replacement candidates and make the replacement then close and save and move on to the next file and do the same thing until it runs out of files?

Comment: Well.....yes, you can surround the code in a loop to walk through all of the files and make the required changes. Are all of them in the same folder?

Comment: they can be moved to one converted then moved back but currently they are in 28 subfolders.

Comment: Kindly check my update and accept my answer, if it solves your issue

Comment: Was this helpful? Did it answer your question?